# Keycloak log files in Docker

Tags: java, docker, logging, keycloak

I want `server.log` file to log events like successful logins, logouts, etc. With some additional information like `User-Agent` etc. For that, I wrote an SPI (mostly copied code from `JBossLoggingEventListenerProvider.java` & `JBossLoggingEventListenerProviderFactory.java`) and deployed the SPI successfully, it appears in `Events -> Config` tab and even generates my desired logs on the console.

Now, when I go to the location: `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log` inside the Docker and open it, my relevant logs aren't there. I tried different options like:

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-February/009498.html
http://www.programmersought.com/article/30541589587/

But still no success. Please let me know how can I enable my event listener to write the logs to the `server.log` file inside the Docker.

Comment: Logs are written to stdout/stderr. Check docker logs command

Comment: I checked, but how should I download these log files to the host machine? and why `server.log` isn't making the logs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Containers don't write logs to files usually, because they use "ephemeral" file system. They write logs to `stdout/stderr` usually and then Docker daemon manage their logs. You have option to configure [Docker logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) and you can manage container on the Docker daemon level. Container log dump (if default logging driver is used):

```
docker logs <contaner> > <logfile.txt>
```

Of course you can configure app (Keycloak in your case) to write logs for logfile and then use volume. This kind of advance Keycloak log configuration is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Yes, I tried the above command and it worked, thanks for your answer and explanation, I kept beating my head all weekend and wasn't able to understand why it is not writing logs. Also, how will I be able to make docker or keycloak generate log files periodically? Will it be through volumes?

Comment: @FaizanHussainRabbani You are expecting old school non Docker approach for log files. Switch to nondockerized version, when you have this kind of expections and your life will be easy or try to learn how logging works in the Docker world.